# Information Graphic

Tags: css, html, html5-canvas, data-visualization

[image]
[image]
I am trying to create a interactive info graphic [image](http://www.pia.com.au/en/sydney-property-investment/) like this. However, mapping through the coordination is not a promising solution. The resolution will be losing when scale these images.

So, is there any other tool or css animation could form the infographic, and make the data more visualise.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It will be ease if you use .svg images, they never lose resolution when scaling.